# Getting error on MongoDb aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi, robo3t

I have been building my app locally with all working fine, which uses the latest MongoDB 3.4 and my aggregate call works fine.

```
app.get('/random_menu', function (req, res) {
    Menus.aggregate([{$sample: {size: 1}}], function (err, data) {
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

I have now moved my code to my raspberry pi which is limited to MongoDB 2.4.10 and it seems my aggregate function will not work on it. My app doesn't return any data and there are no errors.

To test I tried it via RoboMongo, with the following, which works fine on the local 3.4 version:

```
db.getCollection('menus').aggregate([{$sample: {size: 1}}])
```

But when I try it on the pi db via RoboMongo, I get the following error:

```
assert: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "Pipeline::parseCommand(): unrecognized field \"cursor",
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1

Error: command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "Pipeline::parseCommand(): unrecognized field \"cursor",
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1
```

I have tried googling this and can't seem to find anything. I am reletively new to MongoDB so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB 2.4 was first released in March, 2013 and reached end of life in March, 2016 (six months before MongoDB 3.4.0 was available). Testing against a newer release is likely to lead to accidentally using backwards-incompatible features or APIs. Aside from missing features, end-of-life server releases are likely missing important bug fixes and security improvements and will no longer be tested against current driver releases.

Your question highlights issues with two features that did not exist in MongoDB 2.4:

- The `$sample` aggregation stage, which was added in MongoDB 3.2.

  As a workaround for sampling with pre-3.2 versions of MongoDB, I suggest using the NPM package [`mongodb-collection-sample`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-collection-sample) in your application code. This uses `$sample` if supported or a [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) algorithm for older versions of MongoDB.
- Cursor-based aggregation, which was added in MongoDB 2.6.

  This is indicated by the `unrecognized field "cursor"` error. MongoDB 2.6+ drivers default to using a cursor in order to iterate large result sets; older releases were limited to inline results (up to 16MB). Your version of Robomongo embeds a newer shell than MongoDB 2.4 (you can check this with `version()`) and doesn't appear to support 2.4-style aggregation queries with the `aggregate()` helper. There is alternative syntax to call [`aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/) via `db.runCommand()` instead of the `aggregate()` helper, but upgrading to a supported server version would be a better approach.

If you are new to MongoDB, I would definitely encourage using supported releases (MongoDB 3.0 or newer as at March, 2017) and using the same major version in your dev & deployment environments where possible.

As at MongoDB 3.4, Raspberry Pi is not officially supported platform. However, there are [community packages for ArchLinux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages) that others have had success with. Raspberry Pi's limited hardware resources generally aren't suited for much heavy lifting, so an alternative to consider would be using the Pi to run your Node application but connect to a remotely hosted database server.

Comment: Thanks @Stennie for the thorough explanation and advice.

Answer (score 1):

[$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) is available from v3.2.

Comment: Thanks Alex, do you know of an alternative I can use to get the same functionality?

Comment: No, but if you just need a random document from a collection you can `db.getCollection('menus').find().skip(random_number).limit(1)`, where random_number should be between 0 and  `db.getCollection('menus').find().count()`